# apache-airflow 1.9 default timezone set to non utc

Tags: timezone, utc, airflow

I had recently upgraded airflow version from airflow 1.8 to apache-airflow 1.9, the upgrade was successful and I have scaled the environment using Celery Executor, everything seemed to be working fine but the dag and tasks start dates, execution dates etc all are appearing in UTC timezone and the scheduled dags are running in UTC, earlier before the upgrade they used to run in Local timezone which is pdt.

Any ideas on how to make pdt as the default timezone in airflow?

I have tried using `default_timezone` in the `airflow.cfg` to `default_timezone = pdt` but even after restarting all the services it schedules the dags and tasks in UTC. Looking forward to your help on fixing the default timezone to pdt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Airflow running in the local timezone prior to version 1.9.0 was unintended and just a side effect of Airflow code using `datetime.now()` and `datetime.today()` instead of `datetime.utcnow()`. This was rectified in 1.9.0 under [AIRFLOW-289](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-289), making things timezone independent (always UTC) as you have observed.

Official support for Airflow to be timezone aware is merged into the master branch. This work was completed as part of [AIRFLOW-288](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-288) and is **not** available in the latest stable version (1.9.0). You can probably expect it in the next major release.

Once you have that change, Matt's answer should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks Daniel! for your response, this is good information and answers my issue. Just checking if there is any other option available for running dags in non-utc .i.e by making changes to any packages, installation, dag code etc..

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of a simple way. I think your best bet would be to use a fork off of v1.9.0 with the [change](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2618) reverted (might be messy) until timezones is officially released or use the master branch which already has timezone support.

Comment: @DanielHuang, I am using airflow v1.10.1 and changed `default_timezone = Asia/Kolkata` but it is showing UTC date in airflow UI. Is it still unresolved?

Comment: @Kaushal I am getting the same error. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

According to [these docs](http://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timezone.html), the `default_timezone` accepts an IANA TZ Database time zone identifier.  They are listed here.

If you want US Pacific Time, you should set `default_timezone=America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: I had tried default_timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles', it did not work it still working in UTC, the dags are getting triggered in UTC.

Comment: Did you see http://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags

Comment: Yes Matt, I also tried to make the dags timezone aware using the docs but I got the error ``` File "/opt/python27_enhanced-virtual-hadoop/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/ti_deps/deps/exec_date_after_start_date_dep.py", line 24, in _get_dep_statuses
if ti.task.start_date and ti.execution_date < ti.task.start_date:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes``` Ultimately the answers from Daniel above provides the correct information