# Airflow: Execution date is in future when launching from web-ui

Tags: airflow

I'm using airflow v1.9.0.

When I trigger a dag from the web-ui, the execution date is in my local time, which means that for airflow the task is scheduled in the future.

How can I configure the webserver to use *it's* local time over mine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache-airflow 1.9 default timezone set to non utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194000/apache-airflow-1-9-default-timezone-set-to-non-utc)