# Airflow cron not running in timezone

Tags: airflow

I have airflow setup with `default_timezone = US/Eastern`. If I set a DAG with `schedule_interval="0 17 * * *"` it runs at 12pm instead of the expected 5pm. I understand that airflow stores all dates as UTC. How can I get something to run in my timezone instead of writing the interval in UTC?

I have also tried setting the `tzinfo` in the dag's `start_date` to `pendulum.timezone('US/Eastern')` with no luck.

`airflow=1.10.0
rhel7
python=3.6
server's tz = EST`

Comment: Can you try this with `1.10.1rc2` and see if it works. You can do so by `pip install apache-airflow==1.10.1rc2`

Comment: @kaxil can you elaborate on what may have changed in the RC? Should what I have be working as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airflow timezone for configration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875854/airflow-timezone-for-configration-file)