# Apache Airflow | Unable to change default timezone in airflow.cfg

Tags: python, airflow

Unable to change default timezone in airflow.cfg

Hello Folks,

I am unable to change my default time to UTC+1:00, I tried changing that in airflow.cfg file as well.

```
[core]
default_timezone = system
default_timezone = Europe/Amsterdam
default_timezone = utc+1:00
```

Theses are the above things tried, but none on them seems to be working !

Airflow v1.10.2 in use

Comment: Make sure you are setting `default_timezone` in `[core]` section of `airflow.cfg`

Comment: You just need the following, no other setting other than `default_timezone = Europe/Amsterdam` in `[core]`

Comment: @kaxil yes I did that, those mentioned above are the tried once(mentioned all at one go for easy understanding). However I just entered one at a time to see if it works, but it does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airflow timezone for configration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875854/airflow-timezone-for-configration-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this [way](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/2781/files):

```
from airflow.utils import timezone
execution_date = timezone.utcnow()
```

Instead of

```
import datetime
execution_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
import pendulum 

current_date = pendulum.datetime.now().strftime("%Y, %m, %d, %H")
...
    start_date = pendulum.strptime(current_date, "%Y, %m, %d, %H").astimezone('Europe/London'),
...
```